# Struts no action mapped issue

Tags: eclipse, jsp, tomcat, struts2

When deploying a struts application to tomcat running in eclipse I'm getting the following error to the console when trying to load the welcome page.

"There is no Action mapped for namespace / and action name . - [unknown location]"

I was trying to follow the tutorial at: http://viralpatel.net/blogs/2009/12/tutorial-create-struts-2-application-eclipse-example.html.

I am obviously just getting started with struts and any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Best place to start is with official struts2 documentation: http://struts.apache.org/2.x/docs/tutorials.html If you are getting that error message your web.xml is probably Okay. Show your struts.xml file.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to have the URL-Pattern mapped to Struts in your web.xml file.

```
<filter>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
```

Make sure you have the action name then mapped to a Java class in your struts.xml.

```
<action name="find" class="findAction" method="input">
     <interceptor-ref name="myStack" />
     <result name="input">find</result>
</action>
```

These are the essentials.  The result will then need mapped to a JSP.  Good Luck.